# Stumped about Unknown Column in fieldlist

Tags: mysql

I can't seem to find the error in my query. The error i'm getting is "Unknown column 'reg.id' in 'field list'. Can you please point me in the right direction and help others who view this post after me?

My Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT reg.id, reg.key_recordID, reg.regType
FROM Vegas_Annual_Dinner_2017.reg reg1
LEFT JOIN Vegas_Annual_Dinner_2017.reg reg2 ON reg1.id=reg2.main_ID
WHERE reg.status = 'Invited' AND reg.registrationType = 'Student'
```

Comment: Your aliases are named `c1` and `c2`, not `reg`..

Comment: sorry, updated the code. Still getting the error.

Comment: Your aliases are named `reg1` and `reg2` not `reg`..

Comment: What @thebjorn is saying...  you are referencing `reg` in your column list but have alised `reg` with `reg1` and `reg2`.  MySQL is no longer able to reference reg....     SELECT DISTINCT `reg`.id, `reg`.key_recordID, `reg`.regType...   update the column list with the alias you want to project